# Use an External file to replace special characters?

Tags: python, sqlite, config

My question may be confusing but, please do excuse me i'm new to SO, I have a set of names of countries like below in a sqlite table ! !

### Namesofcountries

"America$"
"Brazil--"
"'Czech''''"
;Dubai
^^England''

In the above list i need to replace all the special characters with empty spaces, i'm able to do it with this code !

> cur.execute('select replace( replace( replace( replace( @str, '!', '' ), '\', '' ), '/', '' ), '&', '' )')

it is ok for now and it is working, but i need all the characters to be replaced in a seperate config file or an normal external file that is called and then replaced, that it becomes easy if i need to add some more characters to be relaced in the future.

Can u please explain me out or an example ?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you want. It seems you are asking for someone to provide you a Python script that does what your SQL code does, but which can be applied to normal text files instead of database columns.  To get help on StackOverflow you need to make an effort to solve the problem (i.e. write the Python code) yourself. When you encounter difficulty, post what you have done and then ask a _specific_ question.  In general, SO people do not react well to "please write my code for me" requests.

Comment: Sorry ! Mr.Jim i did not want others to write a program for me, but i'm a beginner and could not get into how to perfectly structure a python program !

and the other thing i dont want a replica of that characters to be replaced into python, instead i dont have an idea how to put all those special characters into a txt file and call them while replacing !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet but I wanted to add that it seems likely that there will be different bad characters in future lists.

Perhaps it would be better to only keep good characters?

```
import string
good_characters= string.ascii_letters # a-z, A-Z
```

then where the above answer has

```
for bad_char in special_chars:
    country = country.replace(bad_char, '')
```

instead use

```
country = ''.join(s if s in good_characters else ' ' for s in country).strip()
```

Not at all easy to follow but here goes:

```
(s if s in good_characters else ' ' for s in country)
```

create a tuple of all the characters in country (that's the "for s in country" part)
but, use the letter if it is a letter and use a space if it is not (that's the "if s in good_character else ' '" part)

`''.join(...)` turns the tuple back into a string

`.strip()` takes off the extra spaces at the front and back that are left by replacing bad characters with spaces.

Even though I have been taught that you should try to use string methods before using regular expressions I think I would have approached this with re just to avoid the comprehension and chaining of methods...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are relatively new to Python. Welcome. I'm a stranger here myself, as the saying goes.

Jim is correct when he says that you should be making an attempt on this code rather than asking it be written for you. That said, giving you the benefit of the doubt I will walk you through my own and hopefully it will be a learning experience

```
char_cfg = open('9188651a.txt', 'r')
special_chars = char_cfg.readline()
char_cfg.close()
```

These 3 lines open a text file for reading, read the first line into a string called special_chars and then close the cfg file since we no longer need it. My 9188651a.txt file simply looks like this:

```
!\/&"-$;^
```

it just contains the characters we wish to replace, in no particular order.

The next three lines are very much similar, opening a second file that contains the "dirty" country names which we need to replace:

```
ucountries = open('9188651b.txt', 'r')
list_countries = ucountries.readlines()
ucountries.close()
```

Note one key difference: I used the readlines() method instead of readline(). This method reads the entire file and places each line in the file as a string in a list. This can be a very convenient way to read and store the contents of a multi-line file. My 9188651b.txt file contained the following test data:

```
"America$"
"Brazil--"
"Czech"""
;Dubai
^^England"
```

I finish the code with:

```
countries = open('9188651c.txt', 'w')

for country in list_countries:
    for bad_char in special_chars:
        country = country.replace(bad_char, '')
    countries.write(country)

countries.close()
```

The first and last lines are the simplest to understand: I open a third file, 9188651c.txt to write my output to (denoted by the 'w' flag in the open() method call). If this file doesn't already exist, Python will automagically create it for us. I close the file when I am done writing to it. This is standard coding practice in all programming languages.

The meat of this program consists of the four lines in between.

```
for country in list_countries:
```

says, "Loop through the entire list of countries we created earlier, executing this suite of commands once each time through." Python allows you to loop over all items in a data structure in a very natural way. This is one reason people sometimes refer to Python as 'executable pseudocode'.

```
for bad_char in special_chars:
```

says, "Loop through the string we read from the char_cfg file, doing something for each character in the string." Since this for loop is inside of the other for loop, we will actually go through this for loop multiple times, once for each of the iterations of the outer loop.

```
country = country.replace(bad_char, '')
```

simply says, "replace all occurrences of bad_char within the country string (which is one item in the list_countries list of strings) with '', or nothing." We are saving the changed string back in the same spot in list_countries.

Finally,

```
countries.write(country)
```

writes our modified string (country) into the next line of the output file. Note the indentation of this code relative to our loops; we want it executed once per country rather than once per bad character, so we place it at the proper indentation such that Python includes that command in the outer loop but not the inner loop.

Sure enough, our output file can be checked to now be:

```
America
Brazil
Czech
Dubai
England
```

Fair warning, you're not likely to be given the benefit of the doubt like this very often. People taking the time to reply expect that you've taken the time to try it yourself before posting your question. Good luck with Python and be sure to hang around - Stack Overflow is a fantastic resource once you learn how to use it properly.

Comment: Than Q !! very much Mr.iamchuckB, i'm sorry if i were wrong in about asking for a help in the question ! i'll try doing my best from the next time onwards

This works great !

Comment: Don't worry about it, just remember it in the future as people will expect it of you. On a related note, there is a **great** reading list for learning Python from scratch - along with a recommended pacing - at [MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/readings/). Python is a great first programming language.